# Firebase Realtime Database not updating in Android app

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am doing a really simple "hello world" with Firebase and Realtime Database.

However, the example isn't working.  I am not getting any errors either:

```
//connect to firebase
final FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
final DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference("message");

//write to database
 myRef.setValue("I'm writing data" + UUID.randomUUID().toString(), 
newDatabaseReference.CompletionListener() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(DatabaseError databaseError, 
DatabaseReference databaseReference) {
                    if (databaseError != null) {
                        System.out.println("Data could not be saved " + 
databaseError.getMessage());
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("Data saved successfully.");
                    }
                }
            });
```

I don't see any errors in my logs and the "onComplete" listener is never called.

Do I have to do something to "push" the data remotely?

Thanks

Comment: Nope, nothing additional should be needed. Are you sure the device is able to make a connection to the Firebase servers? If you're not certain, [enable debug logging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/FirebaseDatabase.html#setLogLevel(com.google.firebase.database.Logger.Level)) and check your logcat output.

Comment: Thanks.  The enable debug logging helps.  I am getting SSL errors because my company puts their certificate between all requests.  I thought this might be the issue but I wasn't seeing any errors in the logs.  Is there somewhere you can add a certificate for firebase sdk to trust?  I tried adding it to the emulator but no luck.

Comment: Firebase has no mechanism for this. It purely relies on Android for its sockets.